# How configure apt-get with proxy

Tags: apt

I'm new one on elementary, I work behind a proxy.  I cant get work apt -get behind a proxy  , i tried to edit  **/etc/apt/apt.conf** but i can't find, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

finally i created a file apt.conf in /etc/apt/ , and i filled with

Acquire::http::proxy "http://:"; 
Acquire::https::proxy "http://:"; 
Acquire::ftp::proxy "http://:";

rebooted and it worked